# Edgar Package | Issue with .txt files

Tags: r, text, error-handling, package, edgar

Thank you already in advance for your input.

My issue is the `getSentimentCount(word.frq, words.list)` function of the edgar package. The function is supposed to read the `word.list` which is a .txt file and compare the content of another existing list `(word.frq)`, also a .txt file.

This works fine for one .txt file which has no spaces between words, but R can still read the file as if there were (count > 1). The other file can be read (count > 1) if there is a new line after each word, but results in an error of the `getSentimentCount(word.frq, words.list)` function. If the .txt file is stripped of the new lines and all words put as one line (as other file) then R can only read one word (basically all the words in one line) and count = 1.

Are there different types of .txt files that R distinguishes?

[LINK](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jyujuuy7qx0jwp0/AABsZNqfI8fwERfObqN2Tb2da?dl=0) to both .txt files. `negwords.txt` works, `litwords.txt` results in an error.

I am grateful for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: The function`getSentimentCount(word.frq, words.list)`only reads`.txt (MS-DOS)`.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that R reads only one word in the `nospace` txt is normal: as far as R is concerned, this is just one character string without any separator.

I don't have any issue reading the other docs :

```
library(edgar)
wf <- getWordfrquency("R/litwords_space.txt")
neg <- readLines("R/negwords.txt")
wgs <- getSentimentCount(word.frq = wf, words.list = neg)
```

For now, your list of words just contains words which appear once, so the frequency table will always be one.

If ever you're into text-mining and sentiment analysis, I strongly advice you to switch to the `tidytext` package.

Colin

Comment: Thanks you for your quick response. I have the issue with reading the `litwords.txt` as `words.list` in `getSentimentCount(word.frq, words.list)` but not if just trying to read it with `readLines()` (results in `read items 903`). Doing so results in an error:  "Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : invalid 'row.names' length". Any input on that? Thanks in advance.